# Lenovo t520 Windows 10 SSD upgrade

Tags: windows, boot, laptop, lenovo-laptop, windows-10-upgrade

I wanted to upgrade my Lenovo Thinkpad t520 so I replaced the old HDD with a new Samsung EVO 860 SSD.

I put the SSD in the primary slot and the HDD in the secondary. I installed Windows 10 on my new SSD and the computer works with it but it won't start without my old HDD. I would guess that maybe there are some necessary boot settings saved on it.

Does anybody know how I can make my computer work only with my SSD so I can format the old HDD?

Comment: Probably the EFI partition is in the old drive. If you had remove it before installing, Windows would have created a new EFI partition in the new drive.

Comment: Thanks a lot I removed it, installed Windows 10 again and it worked :)